# Key value schema to store GeoSpatial data?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Developing a bridge to use a cms with MongoDB I use a storage key, value, type to manage all values linked to the cms. These key, types values are stored in the `web.config` to allow an extensible schema. No class object definition is allowed in this case to preserve the dynamic schema. The result is a storage as DynamicArray. This is generating some doubs about performing and the storage of latitude longitude to retrieve in a peform way using `Query.Near` operators.

```
DynamicArray
{  
    item : { Key: "lat", Value: "12.897", Type:double }
    item : { Key: "lng", Value: "12.345", Type:double }  
    item : { Key: "country", Value: "USA", Type:String }  
    item : { Key: "state", Value: "CA", Type:String }  
    item : { Key: "city", Value: "San Jose", Type:String }  
    item : { Key: "district", Value: "", Type:String }   
}

Query.ElemMatch("DynamicArray", Query.And(Query.EQ("Key", "country"), Query.EQ("Value", "USA")));

Query.Near ??
```

It's a schema key value compatible with a GeoSpatial searching? And performant? How to query using official driver a `Query.Near` (C# official driver) in this schema way ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use geo-spatial queries on MongoDB, you need to store your x,y coordinates as the first two values in an object. Examples of valid schemas are:

```
{ loc: [20,30] } 
{ loc: { x: 20, y: 30 }}
{ loc: { foo: 20, y: 30}}
{ loc: { lat : 40.739037, long: 73.992964 } }
```

You cannot separate the coordinates into multiple objects as you have done in your sample above.

For more information: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing